# Add-Instruction is faster than the processor itself

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, cpu-architecture, microbenchmark

I have this code (Some instructions are added for benchmark fairness):

```
.global count_forloop
.global count_addloop
.global count_mulloop
.global count_divloop

count_forloop:
    push %rsi
    push %rcx
    mov $0xFFFFFFFF, %rsi
    add %rsi, %rsi
    xor %eax, %eax
_count_forloop1:
    inc %rax
    cmp $10000000, %rax
    jne _count_forloop1
    pop %rcx
    pop %rsi
    ret

count_addloop:
    push %rsi
    push %rcx
    mov $0xFFFFFFFF, %rsi
    add %rsi, %rsi
    xor %eax, %eax
    xor %ecx, %ecx
_count_addloop1:
    inc %rax
    add $3, %rcx # Benchmark this instruction
    cmp $10000000, %rax
    jne _count_addloop1
    pop %rcx
    pop %rsi
    ret

count_mulloop:
    push %rsi
    push %rcx
    mov $0xFFFFFFFF, %rsi
    add %rsi, %rsi
    xor %eax, %eax
    xor %ecx, %ecx
    add $4, %ecx
_count_mulloop1:
    inc %rax
    imul $3, %rcx # Benchmark this instruction
    cmp $10000000, %rax
    jne _count_mulloop1
    pop %rcx
    pop %rsi
    ret

count_divloop:
    push %rsi
    push %rcx
    mov $0xFFFFFFFF, %rsi
    add %rsi, %rsi
    xor %ecx, %ecx
    add $1, %rcx
_count_divloop1:
    inc %rcx
    div %rsi # Benchmark this instruction
    cmp $10000000, %rcx
    jne _count_divloop1
    pop %rcx
    pop %rsi
    ret
```

and

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#define N 1000

void count_forloop(void);
void count_addloop(void);
void count_mulloop(void);
void count_divloop(void);

uint64_t ns(void);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    uint64_t start_time_for = ns();
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        count_forloop();
    uint64_t end_time_for = ns();
    uint64_t diff_for = (end_time_for - start_time_for) / N;
    printf("10.000.000 iterations of empty forloop: %" PRIu64 "ns\n", diff_for);
    uint64_t start_time_add = ns();
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        count_addloop();
    uint64_t end_time_add = ns();
    uint64_t diff_add = (end_time_add - start_time_add) / N;
    printf("10.000.000 iterations of addloop: %" PRIu64 "ns\n", diff_add);
    printf("10.000.000 iterations of addloop: %" PRIu64 "ns (Excluding for-loop)\n", diff_add - diff_for);
    uint64_t start_time_mul = ns();
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        count_mulloop();
    uint64_t end_time_mul = ns();
    uint64_t diff_mul = (end_time_mul - start_time_mul) / N;
    printf("10.000.000 iterations of mulloop: %" PRIu64 "ns\n", diff_mul);
    printf("10.000.000 iterations of mulloop: %" PRIu64 "ns (Excluding for-loop)\n", diff_mul - diff_for);
    uint64_t start_time_div = ns();
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        count_divloop();
    }
    uint64_t end_time_div = ns();
    uint64_t diff_div = (end_time_div - start_time_div) / N;
    printf("10.000.000 iterations of divloop: %" PRIu64 "ns\n", diff_div);
    printf("10.000.000 iterations of divloop: %" PRIu64 "ns (Excluding for-loop)\n", diff_div - diff_for);
    double real_add = (diff_add - diff_for) / 10000000.0;
    double real_mul = (diff_mul - diff_for) / 10000000.0;
    double real_div = (diff_div - diff_for) / 10000000.0;
    printf ("Add: %lfns\n", real_add);
    printf ("Mul: %lfns\n", real_mul);
    printf ("Div: %lfns\n", real_div);
    printf ("Mul/Add = %lf\n", real_mul / real_add);
    printf ("Div/Add = %lf\n", real_div / real_add);
}

uint64_t ns(void) {
    struct timespec t;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &t);
    return (uint64_t)(t.tv_sec) * (uint64_t)1000000000 + (uint64_t)(t.tv_nsec);
}
```

I wanted to benchmark/compare the length e.g. adding, multiplying and dividing takes.

```
10.000.000 iterations of empty forloop: 2415544ns
10.000.000 iterations of addloop: 3074961ns
10.000.000 iterations of addloop: 659417ns (Excluding for-loop)
10.000.000 iterations of mulloop: 7177428ns
10.000.000 iterations of mulloop: 4761884ns (Excluding for-loop)
10.000.000 iterations of divloop: 43092662ns
10.000.000 iterations of divloop: 40677118ns (Excluding for-loop)
Add: 0.065942ns # Here, this is weird
Mul: 0.476188ns
Div: 4.067712ns
Mul/Add = 7.221355
Div/Add = 61.686487
```

First I just benchmark the calls to count_forloop in order to get the performance of all instructions except the one I want to measure, then I measure the time for the different functions, subtract the time needed for an empty for-loop and then divide until I have the time for one execution of the instruction.

My processor is able to reach 4.2GHz, while running this program, this value is nearly reached on one core.

Let's assume, it is able to reach those 4.2GHz, this means, that each cycle takes `2.381e-10`seconds, or around 0.24 nanoseconds.

But as you can see, the `add` instruction only takes 0.065942ns, so only around one third of one cycle.

I tried running the programming multiple times, but I always get the same result, that `add` is faster than the processor itself.

I can't find any error in my calculations.

Comment: You are confusing clock cycles with instructions. Some instructions can be executed in parallel to each other, so they effectively require less than one clock cycle, while other instructions may need multiple clock cycles...

Comment: Haven't thought of parallel execution of instructions ;D Your explanation helped a lot

Comment: A single core can execute more than one arithmetic operation per cycle. And this can also be used to optimize c and c++ programs.

Comment: @CherryDT: `add $3, %rcx` cannot be executed in parallel with itself because each execution has an input, in `%rcx`, that is dependent on an output, also in `%rcx`, from a previous execution. So there can be at most one execution of it per cycle.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Hm, that's not what the OP's results suggest, though. Do you have another explanation?

Comment: @CherryDT:  That loop will execute at 1 cycle / iteration thanks to the CPU being superscalar, capable of running `add`, `inc`, and macro-fused `cmp/jcc` in the same clock cycle.  Only 32-bit Pentium 4 (before Prescott) could ever execute two dependent `add` instructions in the same cycle, with its double-pumped ALUs.  And no existing x86-64 CPU can execute the taken-branch for the loop faster than 1/clock.

Comment: I suspect some kind of timing error... oh, yeah **the program does `diff_add - diff_for` to subtract the time for an empty loop**!!!   It's implicitly assuming that instruction costs add linearly, and (over)-correcting for it.  Could just as easily have calculated a zero or negative time.  There is a warm-up loop ahead of the "empty" (actually 2-uop `inc` / `cmp+jcc`) loop, so IDK why there's any time difference between those loops.  (ping @EricPostpischil).  I noticed this after wondering why there was no output for cycles / iter of the "for-loop".

Comment: See also [Modern Microprocessors
A 90-Minute Guide!](https://www.lighterra.com/papers/modernmicroprocessors/).  And [RDTSCP in NASM always returns the same value (timing a single instruction)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54621381) re: methodology to time a single instruction for latency or throughput, as in https://uops.info/.  See also https://agner.org/optimize/, and other performance links at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info  e.g. Kanter's deep-dive into a couple Intel microarchitectures: https://www.realworldtech.com/sandy-bridge/ and https://www.realworldtech.com/haswell-cpu/

Comment: My Skylake CPU runs your loop closer to how I expected, with "empty" loop being only 0.5% faster than `add` loop: 5147337ns vs. 5175039ns for a delta of 27702ns.  It's still running the div loop (0.05 IPC according to a `perf stat -I 1000 -p $(pidof a.out)` I attached to it from another terminal, so that iteration count is way too high for Intel CPUs with their slow `div r64`)...  Finally finished, calculating an amusing `0.002770ns` for `add`.  My CPU runs 3.9 GHz for sustained periods, so that's about 100x faster than the actual throughput of that 1/clock `add` loop.

Comment: I'd guess you're on an AMD CPU, or Intel Ice Lake or newer, where `div r64` latency is about the same as 32-bit operand-size `div %esi` for the same actual input values zero-extended.  You're lucky your loop doesn't fault with whatever garbage the caller leaves in RDX:RAX and RSI.  If RDX >= RSI, `div %rsi` would fault since the quotient wouldn't fit in RAX.  (RSI=0 is a special case of that.)  (After the first iteration, where RDX gets the remainder, it's guaranteed less than RSI, like if you were doing extended-precision division.)